# Can someone validate this JavaScript code (to do list)

Tags: javascript

Here's the code...

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6n2k65zs/
```

Try add a new item, you'll see its not working for some reason but it should be...
I can't spot any errors in the code, can someone help me out please?

And does anyone know any good debuggers? debugging JS is a nightmare!

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript To-Do List</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <button id="btn">Add</button>
        <hr>
        <ul id="todo">

        </ul>

        <ul id="done">

        </ul>

<!--        javascript anonymous self-invoking function         -->
<!--        Function expressions will execute automatically     -->
<script>
    // from outside the action you wont be able to access the variables
    // prevents another variable with a same name from conflicting
    (function(){
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
//          Object for the lists
// the reason im using ID is because ID can only be named once rather than a class which can be named 100's of times            
        var lists = {
            todo:document.getElementById('todo'),
            done:document.getElementById('done')
        };

        /*   Parameter is string
         create a list element which is stored in 'el' and returns it
         */
        var makeTaskHtml = function(str, onCheck) {
            var el = document.createElement('li');
            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            var label = document.createElement('span');
            
            label.textContent = str;
            checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
            checkbox.addEventListener('click', onCheck);
//            el.textContent = str;
//            can use this method to move an element from one element to another
            el.appendChild(checkbox);
            el.appendChild(label);
            // Text content is grabbing the text from the text box and storing it in variable el.
            return el;
        };
        var addTask = function(task) {
         lists.todo.appendChild(task);
        };
        
        var onCheck = function(event){
            var task = event.target.parentElement; //targets the item clicked
            var list = task.parentElement.id;
            
            //lists.done.appendChild(task);
            //swaps the 2 objects around
            lists[list === 'done' ? 'todo' : 'done'].appendChild(task);
            this.checked = false;

            input.focus();
            
        };
        
        var onInput = function() {
            var str = input.value.trim; // trim removes white space...
            
            if (str.length > 0) {
                addTask(makeTaskHtml(str, onCheck));
                input.value = '';
                input.focus();
            }
        };
        
        btn.addEventListener('click', onInput);
        input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
            var code = event.keyCode;
            console.log(code);

            if (code === 13) {
             onInput();
            }
        });
        input.focus();
        
        addTask(lists.todo, makeTaskHtml('Test done', onCheck));

    }());

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: F12 is a good debugger :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me you are not calling trim as a method, but accessing it as a variable?

Try add the () in trim:

```
var onInput = function() {
    var str = input.value.trim(); // trim removes white space...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your addTask function is being called with 3 parameters:

> ```
> addTask(lists.todo, makeTaskHtml('Test done', onCheck));
> ```

but the function definition for addTask only takes one parameter:

> ```
> var addTask = function(task)
> ```

so you need to just call addTask with just makeTaskHtml parameter, and not lists.todo which is already referenced inside the addTask function or onCheck

Answer (score 0):

Or for debugging in Chrome, try Cmd-Alt–I in (Mac) or Ctrl-Alt-I (Windows).

First of all, you shouldn't put your scripts inline in JSFiddle – put them in the JS box to protect everyone's sanity! It's what it's made for...

There are other issues in the code, but the main issue seems to be in this line:

```
var str = input.value.trim;
```

Here, you're assigning `str` to the JS function `trim`. You want to assign it the the results of `trim()`, so try:

```
var str = input.value.trim();
```

You're still getting other errors in the console, but the basics seem to work.